# Sanctum: Checking User Authentication Status in Controller. Allowing Access for Guests and Users

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am using sanctum. I have such a controller

```
public function user()
    {
        if (auth('sanctum')->check()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that without middleware `auth:sanctum`, the conditional statement always returns false, and as soon as I use this middlewate, everything works fine. However, I can't use this middleware, because then the user will have to be logged in, and I would like to give access, both to guests and users. How can I do this?
I would like to check in the controller if the user is logged in, and if so, be able to return, for example, the id of that user.

@Update

```
 //This routers works correctly if user is logged-in
//but it doesn't work for guest
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::prefix('panel')->group(function () {
        Route::post('somethig', [SomethingController::class, 'something']);

    });

});

//Into this route it doesn't return user. It'll works for users it I use auth:sanctum middleware
Route::post('display-posts', [PostsControllerFrontend::class, 'displayPosts']);
```

@Edit2
Below I show you Kernel.php - middlewareGroup.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Have you tried with auth()->guest()?

Comment: Can you show your routes ?
@Pippo `auth()->guest()` === `!auth()->check()`

Comment: It display me I'm guest.

Comment: Are your routes in web.php or api.php ?

Comment: In api.php only

Comment: Sorry but I don't know... I have multiple apps using Sanctum and none is having this problem. Check all your configuration (.env + config files) : auth, sanctum, session... If you run your test from an app like Postman don't forget to add the "Referer" header

Answer (score 0):

for your question, one option you can use is the access [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization), the scope of the sanctum package is shown in the following [example](https://github.com/jonathan-castro1/laravel9_rest/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)

Comment: There is no need for policies here, he just wants to check if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a session problem, didn't you forget the Sanctum's `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware ?
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#sanctum-middleware

Comment: I add this middleware but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Just to be sure, the middleware is in the right group corresponding to your routes (web/api) ? Can you share your routes ?

Comment: I updated my post. Which middleware? If I use `auth:sanctum`. I need to use be logged.

Comment: Please share your `app/Http/Kernel.php` `$middlewareGroups` property too.